# Hazelcast Jet - submit job to remote Kubernetes cluster

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have a Jet (3 instance) cluster setup in a Kubernetes cluster (Openshift). I would like to submit the job to it. I used proxy to connect but the job isnt submitted. I also tried to upload the far jar file to one of the cluster pod and submit from there - unfortunately I get unable to connect to any cluster.

### EDIT: Additional cluster details

```
Cluster installation: Helm
Type: Stateful
Replicas: 3
service: proxying 3 pods
```

I use port-forward to connect to Jet cluster

`oc port-forward --namespace jet svc/jet-cluster-hazelcast-jet 5701:5701`

Then if I issue the `jet.sh cluster` command from my system, I get unable to connect to any Jet cluster error.

Then to submit the job I use,

`jet.sh submit -v target/job1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No available connection to address [10.129.1.251]:5701
```

Any docs, examples would be of great help.

Comment: Could you provide some more details and your setup? There is an example here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-docker/tree/master/examples/kubernetes

Comment: Additional details added to the question